# Monitoring Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How can I monitor the following metrics for Azure SQL Database:
- Buffer Cache hit ratio.
- Page life expectancy.
- Page Splits.
- Lock waits.
- Batch requests.
- SQL compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for **dynamic management views**. A good starting point will be
[Monitoring Azure SQL Database using dynamic management views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs).

Regarding Buffer Cache hit, Page life etc. check this blog
[SQL Server memory performance metrics – Part 4 – Buffer Cache Hit Ratio and Page Life Expectancy](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-4-buffer-cache-hit-ratio-page-life-expectancy/)

Comment: No way for monitoring it using Azure Log analytics or Azure Application Insights?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The new [Azure SQL Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-sql)

> Azure SQL Analytics is a cloud monitoring solution for monitoring
>   performance of Azure SQL Databases at scale across multiple elastic
>   pools and subscriptions. It collects and visualizes important Azure
>   SQL Database performance metrics with built-in intelligence for
>   performance troubleshooting on top.

Answer (score 0):

Performance counters on SQL Azure only collect SQL Server counters of a specific database and do not show Windows performance counters (like Page Life Expectancy). For some performance counters you need to take a first snapshot, then a second snapshot, and then you should substract values of counters between snapshots to get the actual counter value.

Please use the script provided on the following article to properly collect those counters.

[Collecting performance counter values from a SQL Azure database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2015/04/02/collecting-performance-counter-values-from-a-sql-azure-database/).